# How to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection in the console application?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

On the page [Non-DI aware scenarios for Data Protection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/non-di-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-3.1) I find the code that is intended to be a console application.

It is unexpected for me because console application references to ASP.NET Core library:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;
```

When I tried to run it, I expectedly got an error message about missing assembly.

I asked Microsoft about this https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/17098. But I just got the come-off answer, I just got the reference to the page which is upper in the content: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1#package-layout

When I run the code in the ASP.NET app, the following statement `dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector("Program.No-DI")` returned `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector`.

Which library contains `KeyRingBasedDataProtector`?

I included the package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions/, but it expectedly does not contain implementation.

In general, are ASP.NET libraries are suitable to use in console applications?

After all, how to run the code from the page [Non-DI aware scenarios for Data Protection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/non-di-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-3.1)?

Answer (score 4):

I included 3 packages to the console project:

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Extensions

This makes the console project working.

Comment: You could've given nuget links to the packages...